# no route.h on the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, c, networking, network-programming

I am trying to build some code that is originally target at OSX/BSD/Linux for the iPhone. It uses `struct rt_msghdr` from `route.h` but as it turns out this header is not available in the iPhone SDK.

Looks like the function tries to find the available bind addresses as a list of `struct addrinfo`.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to proceed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the header into the project and change the includes to be local, that often works for me.

Comment: Surprisingly (at least to me) that did indeed work. Still odd it's not included in the SDK. But thanks to the pointer! At least I got it compiling now.

Comment: I noticed that the header was present in the Simulator SDK but not in the iPhone SDK (3.2+).

Comment: Copying `route.h` works well. Strange that it is not a part the iOS SDK. Does copying https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/master/bsd/net/route.h into my iOS app and using it as it is require me to do anything in my app for licensing requirements? Or I can use if for free without having to say anything on my app's About page? My app is going to get deployed in US and Europe.